# onactivityresult() is never called

Tags: java, android, onactivityresult

I am trying to send mail from my app.The problem is after successful/unsuccessful delivery of the email it doesn't return to the activity, meaning that `onActivityResult()` is not being called.

Here is my code:

```
String[] recipients = {"soham@gmail.com"};
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, Uri.parse("mailto:"));

// prompts email clients only
email.setType("message/rfc822");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);

try{
    // the user can choose the email client
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an email client from..."), 1);
}catch(android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex){

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode == 1){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        }else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673371/how-to-move-again-mainactivity-after-sending-the-mail) but not working for me. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong.

**Edit**

I got the problem.It will work fine in Activity.But it will not work on *Fragment* or *FragmentActivity*. All fragment is closing down forcefully.You can say my app is going on the background.How to solve this issue?Anybody got any idea.

Comment: I just tested this and it gets into `onActivityResult()`, but it always gets into RESULT_CANCELED with no extras in the Intent.  Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778048/how-can-we-use-startactivityforresult-for-email-intent

Comment: @DanielNugent, when I am starting the intent ,my app is closing down.It's not calling the  onActivityResult() result,after finishing or cancelling.I am calling this from FragmentActivity,will be it a problem

Comment: Get look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment

Answer (score 0):

If i uderstand your problem correctly;

In your activity's onActivityResult part you can find your fragment

```
YourFragment fragment = (YourFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_framelayout_id);
```

And use your fragment's public method:

```
if(fragment != null)
{
   fragment.yourPublicMethod();   
}
```

In yourPublicMethod you can do whatever you want. I hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks for your answer.My problem is if I call Intent.ACTION_SEND from a fragment  or fragmentActivity then my app is closing down or going in the background.